# Display the image in the browser without any extension & path of directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, path

I wan't to display the image in the browser without any extension & path of directory search only images by their name in the browser followed by the name of root dirctory.

for eg. I have

```
localhost/uploader/images/i/img.jpg
 localhost/uploader/images/d/dog.jpg
 localhost/uploader/images/p/pea.jpg
 localhost/uploader/images/s/saree.jpg
```

I got the solution as create file .htaccess with the code as

```
Options +MultiViews
```

this generate result as

```
localhost/uploader/images/i/img
 localhost/uploader/images/d/dog
 localhost/uploader/images/p/pea
 localhost/uploader/images/s/saree
```

but I want to display the images of any directory in my root dir uploader as

```
locahost/uploader/img
 locahost/uploader/dog
 locahost/uploader/pea
 locahost/uploader/saree
```

thanks.

Comment: Could have better spent your time researching the problem instead of writing this question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your root dir in .htaccess place

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^uploader/([a-zA-Z0-9])([^/]+)$ uploader/images/$1/$1$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this should redirect the files the way you want

Comment: Its not helping but if 
we can insert the url as
'locahost/uploader/img'
then it should jump the url from upper url to
'localhost/uploader/images/i/img'

Comment: then maybe this `RewriteRule ^uploader/([a-zA-Z0-9])([^/]+)$ uploader/images/$1/$1$2.jpg [L]` you have to try to customize it a bit...